# Multigroup comparison in R - comparing model fit?

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, lavaan

**Background:** I am running a structural equation model with a latent factor (using lavaan), to predict memory function by gender. I have ascertained that I have measurement invariance using the semTools function *measurementInvariance*. I now want to see which regression coefficients in the model significantly differ by my grouping variable, gender.

**Analysis:** I have compared my unconstrained model with a model with *all* regression paths constrained:

```
# unconstrained model
unconstrained.model <- '
latent1=~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6
V1 ~~ V2

immediate_memory ~ latent1
delayed_memory ~ immediate_memory + latent1'

#fit the model
unconstrained.fit <-sem(unconstrained.model, mydata, group="gender")

# all regression coefficients constrained to be equal
allregconstrained.fit <-sem(unconstrained.model, mydata, group="gender",
group.equal = c("regressions"))

# test fit of unconstrained vs fully constrained models 
anova(unconstrained.fit , allregconstrained.fit) #sig different fit
```

The comparison of model fit was significant - therefore I want to see which regression coefficients in the model significantly differ by gender. I tried constraining *one* regression paths to see where group differences lie:

```
#constrain individual path to see where group differences lie
1regconstrained.modelA <- '
latent1=~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6
V1 ~~ V2

immediate_memory ~ c(a,a)*latent1
delayed_memory ~ immediate_memory + latent1'

#fit the model
1regconstrained.fitA <-sem(1regconstrained.modelA, mydata, group="gender")

# test fit of unconstrained vs constrained (1 path only) models 
anova(unconstrained.fit , 1regconstrained.fitA) #sig different fit
```

The first model comparison was significant. I believe this means the constrained path differs by gender. I then tried constraining a different path:

```
#constrain different individual path to see where group differences lie
1regconstrained.modelB <- '
latent1=~ v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 + v6
V1 ~~ V2

immediate_memory ~ latent1
delayed_memory ~ c(b,b)*immediate_memory + latent1'

#fit the model
1regconstrained.fitB <-sem(1regconstrained.modelB, mydata, group="gender")

# test fit of unconstrained vs constrained (1 path only) models 
anova(unconstrained.fit , 1regconstrained.fitB) #sig different fit
```

**Problem:** I am getting identical output when comparing the constrained path (immediate_memory ~ c(a,a)*latent1) and the unconstrained model, and the constrained path (delayed_memory ~ c(b,b)*immediate_memory) and the unconstrained model. This doesn't seem right! This is my output:

```
           Df   AIC   BIC  Chisq Chisq diff Df diff Pr(>Chisq)    
Saturated   0               0.00                                  
Model     158 98882 99501 320.06     320.06     158  4.556e-13 ***
```

I assume I am critically misunderstanding some part of the process/concepts involved in this analysis.  I have trawled through multiple text books and webpages, but most sections on multigroup analysis focus on measurement invariance, rather than comparing the models by group after invariance has been met. Any guidance as to where I am going wrong would be appreciated an incredible amount.

Thank you for any help you can offer.